# Как избавиться от ложных срабатываний антивируса на крайне простую программу Python?

Tags: python, urllib

У меня есть код на `Python`. Все что он делает, это принимает в виде аргумента консоли ссылку, а затем скачивает содержащийся там файл.

**Код:**

```
import urllib.request
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(sys.argv[1], 'File.exe')
        print('\nФайл загружен')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'\nНе удалось загрузить файл\n{e}')
```

Это всего лишь вспомогательный файл для основной программы. Нужен для скачивания обновлений с GitHub.

Суть в том, что после компиляции в .exe, на `VirusTotal` он получает **33 срабатывания**.
[Ссылка на страницу проверки на VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ad07a3ab42a949035804ce7422a89a68e1389138377edee53b77d82c782b049a/detection)

**Как с этим вообще бороться?**

---

Я прибегал к использованию `Cython`, чтобы затем скомпилировать уже C-Код, но с этим возникает куча проблем (при конвертации кода в C, постоянно возникают какие-то ошибки). Капаться в других языках ради написания такой простой проги тоже не сильно хочется. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Добавить embedded python и к нему написать обертку для запуска  (да на другом языке или можно 
 через bat). Минус размер скорее всего прилично увеличится..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данного скрипта проблема решилась по предложению из комментариев - скачал `embedded python` и просто запускаю код через него.

Для более крупных программ, исходный код которых раскрывать не хочется, самое простое решение - написать во все антивирусы с просьбой перепроверить программу и добавить ее в список исключений.

Также помогло добавление SSL-сертификата, но это платно.

В совокупности, эти 2 решения снизили у полноценной Python-программы кол-во антивирусов с **31** до **4**.